# what are the limits to judicial review in India?

Tags: india

the various articles of the constitution (chapter-The Union Judiciary) regarding the supreme court seem to give the impression that their conduct is heavily regulated by presidential consent and laws made by parliament. but am I missing something ?

edit: it appears that in the chapter dealing with the union list. the parliament has the power to make laws limiting the jurisdiction and powers of supereme court. is this true ?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_List

Comment: This is a very vague and general question making it hard to answer sensibly

Comment: I editited it a bit @ohwilleke basically my question is. doesn't the supreme court have jurisdiction over all matters related to the constitution ? the chapter I mentioned of the constitution (which has the articles related to supreme court) and the union list (which has the power to make laws regulating conduct of supreme court. makes it seem like the parliament can limit the supreme court's jurisdiction very broadly